# List item height variable according to content size

Tags: html, html-lists

This may be a very simple question, but I am not being able to find this and I need an answer to this quickly. What attribute should I look into, if I want the height of each list item in a list box variable depending on the amount of content.

Edit

I am trying to integrate facebook into my website and I have done this so far http://grab.by/v4cI . However, if you see the alignment is not proper because the size of each list item remains constant I think. How can I hange this?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question or give jsfiddle for, what you want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the height auto for the div that contains the list.
Check this out for height property-
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

If you need to display the scrollbar with fixed height then use the following css-

```
div  
{  
  width:150px;  
  height:150px;  
  overflow:scroll;  
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if I am missing something.

Edited-
I saw your screenshot at  http://grab.by/v4cI .
I think you have fixed the height of the div that is holding the listitems. Please make it height auto so that the items don't overflow (because you need it like that).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I was look for varying height sizes for different list items

Comment: @user3392740 OK I understand. But if you know the number of items and the sizes you are going to give to it then you can do it in HTML itself.